# Filling a normal binary tree in ML with values

Tags: sml

Where let's say:

```
datatype bin_tree = Empty |
                    Node of value * bin_tree * bin_tree
```

How would I go about filling a binary tree (not a binary search tree where left is smaller than root and right bigger). Just values from a list inserted at each node in a binary tree.

Comment: Sebastian gave a fine example below, as how to construct one specific tree, however to construct such a `bin_tree` from any list of integers require that you give an algorithm or explanation as how you require the tree to be built.

Answer (score 4):

You use the value constructors you've declared.

If we assume for a moment that `value` is `int` instead, then we for instance have that the tree

```
     1
    / \
   2   4
  /
 3
```

is represented by:

```
Node (1,
    Node (2,
        Node (3, Empty, Empty),
        Empty
    ),
    Node (4, Empty, Empty)
)
```

Or, equivalently, on one line:

```
Node (1, Node (2, Node (3, Empty, Empty), Empty), Node (4, Empty, Empty))
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not really possible to help you, without knowing more about how you wan't your tree constructed from a given list. However here is an example that creates a balanced tree. It takes the first element and uses it as the node value, and then it splits the rest of the list  into two sub lists of equal size (if possible), by taking all "even" element in the "left" list and all "odd" elements in the "right" list:

```
datatype 'a bin_tree = Empty
                  | Node of 'a * 'a bin_tree * 'a bin_tree

fun list_split xs =
    let
      fun loop [] (left, right) = (rev left, rev right)
        | loop (x::y::xs) (left, right) = loop xs (x :: left, y :: right)
        | loop (x :: xs) (left, right) = loop xs (x :: left, right)
    in
      loop xs ([], [])
    end

fun built_tree [] = Empty
  | built_tree (x :: xs)  =
    let
      val (left, right) = list_split xs
      val left_tree = built_tree left
      val right_tree = built_tree right
    in
      Node (x, left_tree, right_tree)
    end
```

The result:

```
- built_tree [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
val it =
  Node
    (1,Node (2,Node (4,Node (8,Empty,Empty),Empty),Node (6,Empty,Empty)),
     Node (3,Node (5,Node (9,Empty,Empty),Empty),Node (7,Empty,Empty)))
  : int bin_tree
```

Answer (score -2):

[Here is an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575349/how-to-fill-a-binary-tree-from-a-string-java/1575378#1575378) to the same question done in Java. This will probably help a good bit :).

Comment: I'm sorry to say, but you couldn't be further from the
truth. That answer is (utterly) useless, specially in this
context.